# How to split a string by multiple delimiters in Dart

Tags: dart, split

If I have a string like this:

```dart
final myFancyCodez = "AA-BB.CC_DD.EE";
```

how can I split it on more than one delimiter?

```dart
expect(fancy.multiSplit( ["-", "."] ), ["AA", "BB", "CC_DD", "EE"] );
expect(fancy.multiSplit( []         ), ["AA-BB.CC_DD.EE"]          );
expect(fancy.multiSplit( ['_']      ), ["AA-BB.CC", "DD.EE"]       );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would personally use something like this instead where we combine the separators into a single regular expression and use the `split` method:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  const fancy = "AA-BB.CC_DD.EE";

  test('Some tests', () {
    expect(fancy.multiSplit(["-", "."]), ["AA", "BB", "CC_DD", "EE"]);
    expect(fancy.multiSplit([]), ["AA-BB.CC_DD.EE"]);
    expect(fancy.multiSplit(['_']), ["AA-BB.CC", "DD.EE"]);
  });
}

extension UtilExtensions on String {
  List<String> multiSplit(Iterable<String> delimeters) => delimeters.isEmpty
      ? [this]
      : this.split(RegExp(delimeters.map(RegExp.escape).join('|')));
}
```

Comment: Very cool! I didn't know about `RegExp.escape` so I didn't consider a regex solution since often in my use cases it involves regex unfriendly subjects like xml strings.

Comment: @JannieTheunissen I did not know about it either but I stumbled into it when I was trying to make a solution for you. When I saw it I was like "ohhhh". :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it:

```dart
extension UtilExtensions on String {

   List<String> multiSplit(Iterable<String> delimeters) {
    if (delimeters?.isEmpty ?? true) return [this];
    if (delimeters.length == 1) return this.split(delimeters.first);
    
    final next = delimeters.skip(1);
    return this
        .split(delimeters.first)
        .expand((i) => i.multiSplit(next))
        .toList();
  }

}
```